# multiple barplots in R side by side

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have two vectors like this:

```
multistakeuserutil<-c(24.0, 71.0, 75.0, 109.0, 134.0, 126.0, 117.0, 446.0, 283.0, 162.0, 109.0)
reguserUtil<-c(10.0, 50.0, 38.0, 67.0, 73.0, 72.0, 69.0, 263.0, 146.0,   87.0, 70.0)
```

Now, I plot multistakeuserutil using this line of code:

```
barplot(multistakeuserutil,col="darkgreen")
```

And then I plot reguserUtil like this:

```
barplot(reguserUtil,col="red")
```

which gives me a separate plot.
But I want this two bar chart to be in one picture and side by side for easier comparison. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be useful for you.

```
test <- cbind(multistakeuserutil,reguserUtil)

barplot(test,beside=T)
```

[image]

If you want to do better comparison, then this is best according to me.

```
test2 <- rbind(multistakeuserutil,reguserUtil)

barplot(test2,beside=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create a second axis for barplot(test2,beside=T)? One for each barplot group (one axis for black, the other for gray).

Answer (score 7):

Use `mfrow()`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1:2))

barplot(multistakeuserutil,col="darkgreen") 
barplot(reguserUtil,col="red")
```

See here for more details and examples: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

[image]

Comment: No, I mean a bar chart that has both variables not two separate bar charts