# Can I make barplots share x-axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, bar-chart

In R, I have `n`-number of barplots of this form

```
y = rnorm(500)
y = matrix(y,100,5)
y.means = abs(apply(y,2,mean))
barplot(y.means, names.arg=1:5)
```

I want these to share the same x-axis. How is that done without using any extra libraries?

Comment: `barplot(matrix(y.means, ncol=1))`? If not, please explain what you mean by "share the same x-axis".

Comment: By sharing the same x-axis I mean that the n number of barplots are laid out directly vertically above one another in the figure such that the bottom barplot has labels on its horizontal axis. These labels are shared between all the above barplots in the sense that the author intends readers to interpret all bars that are aligned horizontally to represent the same quantity.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/36968624/3358272 (using `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`) work?

Comment: These share the y-axis, I want to share x-axis.

Comment: Did you even *try* `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`? It *does* share the x-axis, not the y-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough, thank you for suggesting this. I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of stuffing about and taking advantage of saving `barplot` positions this is possible:

```
vals <- cbind(y.means, newone=y.means)
bp <- barplot(vals, beside=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
barplot(unname(vals), beside=TRUE, names.arg=c(1:5, 1:5) )
axis(1, at=colMeans(bp), labels=colnames(vals), line=2, lty=0)
```

[image]

Comment: That would be to share the y axis. Are you able to modify this answer such that the x-axis is shared instead of y axis? Thanks